# customize_controls_enqueue_scripts doesn't fire from within my plugin

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, theme-customizer

I have a plugin that builds a Class which handles injecting Customizer features.

Within it I am inserting:  Customizer Panel > Section > Settings/Controls

The controls I am I am injecting

- a Select drop-down Input ('type' => 'select',)
- an WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control control

**Both Controls show up, and both work as expected. fantastic**

To improve the experience, I'm trying to modify the controls so that changing the selector hides/shows the Image Upload control accordingly.

I am trying to enqueue a customizer-control.js file using the hook 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'. (I realize that while the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' will pull in my file, it is not scoped to the $wp_customizer object when I do, so I can't use that)

I have a JS script that I want to test (the contents of which are moot right now)
- add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'controls_scripts_enqueue');

**But** *and this is the main problem I'm asking about*....it seems that the customize_controls_enqueue_scripts Hook is not working as expected.

Using XDebug to step through my code, the add_action method is hit, but the Hook action never fires.

In my reading, I see lots of references to "you just have to use 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'" but there is no indication of when it's 'too late' to call to the hook.

### Any insight will help. - Why does 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts' not seem to fire from within my class?

```
    class my_Customize_Theme_Appearance_class {

        private $localization_domain;

        public static function get_instance(){
            if(null == self::$instance){
                self::$instance = new self;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        private function __construct()
        {
            $this->localization_domain = "my-customize-theme-appearance";

            add_action ('customize_register', array($this, 'my_customizer_settings'));
            add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'my_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'); // XDebug hits this line
        }

        public function my_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts () {  // This function is never fired :(
            wp_register_script('header_layout_script', plugins_url('public/js/header_layouts.js', __FILE__ ));
            wp_enqueue_script('header_layout_script');
        }

        public function my_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ) {
            /**
             * Add our Header & Navigation Panel
             */
            $wp_customize->add_panel( 'header_footer_navigation_panel',
                array(
                    'title' => __( 'Header, Footer, & Navigation' ),
                    'description' => esc_html__( 'Adjust Header, Footer, and Navigation options' ),
                    'priority' => 20,
                    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
                )
            );

            /**
             * Header Layouts Switcher
             */
            $wp_customize->add_section('theme_header_layout_section', array(
                'title' => __('Header Layout Select', $this->localization_domain),
                'priority'   => 10,
                'panel' => 'header_footer_navigation_panel'
            ));
            $wp_customize->add_setting('my_header_layout_template_setting', array(
                'default' => 'custom',
                'transport' => 'postMessage'
            ));
            $wp_customize->add_control('my_header_layout_select_control', array(
                    'section' => 'theme_header_layout_section',
                    'settings' => 'my_header_layout_template_setting',
                    'label' => __('Header Layout Select', $this->localization_domain),
                    'description' => __('', $this->localization_domain),
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'choices' => array(
                        'custom' => __('Default (custom)', $this->localization_domain),
                        'dealer_name' => __('Alternate 1', $this->localization_domain),
                        'dealer_logo' => __('Alternate 2', $this->localization_domain),
                    ),
                )
            );
            $wp_customize->add_setting('my_header_logo_image_setting', array(
                'default' => 'placeHolder',
                'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
            ));
            $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'my_header_logo_image_setting', array(
                    'section' => 'theme_header_layout_section',
                    'label' => __('Logo Image', $this->localization_domain),
                    'description' => __('', $this->localization_domain),
                    'mime_type' => 'image',
                    'flex_width' => false,
                    'flex_height' => false,
                    'width' => 250,
                    'height' => 45,
                )));

            $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial('my_header_layout_template_setting', array(
                    'selector' => '#site-header',
                    'container_inclusive' => false,
                    'fallback_refresh' => true
                )
            );

        }

    } //end class
    my_Customize_Theme_Appearance_class::get_instance();
```

Comment: HAH of course it's cross-eyed syndrome

add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'my_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'); 

should be 

add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'my_customize_controls_enqueue_scripts'));

just like the line above it.....